# Move-Item : The input object cannot be bound to any parameters for the command either because the command does not take pipeline input?

Tags: powershell

I wanted to simply move files older that 30 days from "x" to "y"
however I get the following error.. Move-Item : The input object cannot be bound to any parameters for the command either because the command does not take pipeline input or the input and its properties do not match any of the parameters that take pipeline input.

Thought script was simple enough? Any suggestions?

```
# Move All Files From One Location To New Location Older than 30 day(s)
$LocationX = "\\Server\LogFiles\"
$LocationY = "\\BackupServer\LogFiles\"
$Daysback = "-30"
$CurrentDate = Get-Date
$DatetoMove = $CurrentDate.AddDays($Daysback)
Get-ChildItem $LocationX | Where-Object { $_.LastWriteTime -lt $DatetoMove } | Move-Item $LocationX $LocationY -Force
```

Comment: You have filled the parameters that would have filled by the pipeline. The file already knows where it is so there is no need to specify that path. `| Move-Item -Destination $LocationY -Force`

Answer (score 3):

Look at Example 4 from [`Move-Item` on TechNet](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/reference/5.1/microsoft.powershell.management/move-item?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396)

> ```
> PS C:\> Get-ChildItem -Path ".\*.txt" -Recurse | Move-Item -Destination "C:\TextFiles"
> ```

You will see the destination is the *only* specified path parameter. Notice the source path is omitted since the fileinfo object being passed in the pipe will already have that information.

In your pipeline you're filling in the two parameters that would have being matched via the pipeline. Therefore there is no other place to be filled hence the ladder half of the error you are getting.

> the input and its properties do not match any of the parameters that take pipeline input.

So, using your code and the logic from the help you should be able to do this and get the results you expect.

```
Get-ChildItem $LocationX | 
    Where-Object { $_.LastWriteTime -lt $DatetoMove } | 
    Move-Item -Destination $LocationY -Force
```

Comment: THANK YOU WORKED LIKE A CHARM!

Comment: @MarcelPechon YOU ARE MOST WELCOME